# How to continuously run a script with systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I wrote a very simple script (`checkaudio.sh`) that publishes a message from a file on a mqtt topic. I would like the script to run continuously (I would be happy even with every second). I first tried with cron, which is technically possible but "dirty" as a solution (multiple cron jobs with a 1 second delay each).

I have the tried with `systemd` and its `timer` function. I'm not very proficient with systemd, and this is what I came up with:

`/etc/systemd/system/checkaudio@root.service` contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Announce every second

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/checkaudio.sh
```

`/etc/systemd/system/checkaudio@root.timer` contents:

```
[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=1s
AccuracySec=1ms
Unit=checkaudio@root.service
```

I activated the two above through `systemctl enable`.
Everything was running smoothly until I rebooted the system and I could not enable `/etc/systemd/system/checkaudio@root.timer` anymore. I am getting the following error:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve my initial objective of running the script continuously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.timer` unit (not the `.service` unit, which has one but probably shouldn't) is missing an `[Install]` section.

You probably want to add:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Your `.service` file is intended to be activated only by the timer, not directly during boot (etc.). So it shouldn't have an `[Install]` section (and shouldn't be `systemctl enable`'d).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I actually do want my script to be started during boot, or the timer will take care of that?

Comment: @giovi321 add OnBootSec to your timer unit. That'll get the first run on boot. (As the systemd.timer manpage puts it, "For example, by combining OnBootSec= and OnUnitActiveSec=, it is possible to define a timer that elapses in regular intervals and activates a specific service each time.")